# Intellij PlugIn developement - How to create and copy files and folders

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I recently started working with IntelliJ PlugIns.
In school we have a program called BlueJ, which is pretty bad but we have to program in it.
To use IntelliJ instead I always have to copy the java files and create new folders and files.
To go round this tedious task I wanted to write a PlugIn for that but I could not find any help how to do the things mentioned above.
Does anybody know that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are an SDK for that, I'm still what an API that you should use,please read this first.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-started.html